# Files backing loop devices opened without O_EXCL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block-device

Loop devices are the primary way (and perhaps the only way) to treat normal files as block devices in Linux. It's strange that backing files aren't protected by `O_EXCL` flag. Why is that? Why nobody complains?

For example, the tool `wipefs` doesn't notice that the file is mounted:

```
[il@reallin ~]$ touch me
[il@reallin ~]$ truncate -s10G me
[il@reallin ~]$ mkfs.ext3 me
...
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

[il@reallin ~]$ sudo mount -oloop me /mnt

[il@reallin ~]$ mount | grep /mnt
/home/il/me on /mnt type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

[il@reallin ~]$ wipefs -a /dev/loop0
wipefs: error: /dev/loop0: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy

[il@reallin ~]$ wipefs -a me
me: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000438 (ext2): 53 ef

[il@reallin ~]$ uname -a
Linux reallin.basin 4.2.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 23 07:32:38 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If it's to let same file be mounted multiple times, then `losetup` should first try exclusive mode, then print a warning and fallback to not using this flag.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wipefs, but it's possible that it is looking up mounted filesystems and finding 'me' mounted at /mnt.

Comment: @JeffSchaller. Since `util-linux 2.22` this tool additionally probes with O_EXCL https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=865961

Comment: ahhh - did I jump the gun on a self-answer question?